# GS1 Print Zebra

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl, gs1-ai-syntax

I try to print a label. To indicate the fields of a variable, use "_1", "> 8", but the printer throws an error.

```
~JA
^XA
^JM24
^FS
^XA
^LH290,140
^BRR,6,2,1,25,12
^FD01025231270030091117102717171126373104467800300_12144678_13103000300
^FS
^PQ1,0,0,N,Y
^XZ
```

Comment: You are not closing the first `^XA` with `^XZ` (not that you need to put it in a separate XA-XZ anyway), and I'm not sure what you are calling fields of a variable and why the printer would understand `_1` or `> 8`.

Comment: Here's the data (01)02523127003009 (11)171027 (17)171126 (37)3 (10)004467800300 (21)00044678 (3103)000300

Comment: (10) 004467800300 {_1 | <8} (21) 00044678 {_1 | <8} adding a barcode separator is not printed

Comment: Please edit your question to show the data in the way you are sending it to the printer.

Comment: When I send ~JA^XA^JM24^LH290,140^BRR,6,2,1,25,12^FD0102523127003009111710271717112637310446780030021446783103000300^FS^PQ1,0,0,N,Y^XZ, all good!

Answer (score 0):

I add # and all good!

~JA^XA^JM24^LH290,140^BRR,6,2,1,25,12^FD01025231270030091117‌​10271717112637310446‌​7800300#21446783#10300‌​0300^FS^PQ1,0,0,N,Y^‌​XZ